# Solving a challenging differential equation

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How would one go about finding a closed form analytic solution to the following differential equation?

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} +(x^4 +x^2+x+c)y(x) =0 $$

where $c\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: One solution is $y=0$.

Comment: Pretty sure the OP is looking for nontrivial solutions.

Answer (score 5):

You can have a closed form solution in terms of [HeunT (the Heun Triconfluent function)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/31.12)

> $$ y( x ) ={C_1}\,{{\rm e}^{\frac{1}{6}\,ix \left( 2\,{x}^{2}+3\right)}}{\it HeunT} \left(-\frac{{3}^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{2} \left(4\,c-1\right)}{8}, \frac{3\,i}{2}, -\frac{{2}^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{3}}{2}, \frac{i\sqrt [3]{2}\,{3}^{2/3}}{3}x \right) 
> +{ C_2} {{\rm e}^{-\frac{1}{6}\,ix \left( 2\,{x}^{2}+3\right)}}  {\it HeunT } \left( -\frac{{3}^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{2} \left(4\,c-1\right)}{8} ,-\frac{3\,i}{2}, -\frac{{2}^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{3}}{2}, -\frac{i\sqrt [3]{2}\,{3}^{2/3}}{3}x\right).$$

Comment: How in the world would you know to use, think of using, or figure out that you need to use, Triconfluent Heun functions when given such an ode, if you don't mind me asking? It looks nothing like the ode's in your link, for starters.

Comment: May I ask a question? How to see the two parts are linearly independent? Is it a known property of triconfluent Heun? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I would do it.

Let $p(x)=x^4+x^2+x+c$. Put $z=y'$. Then the equation is equivalent to the system 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}y\\ z\end{bmatrix}'=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-p(x)&0\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}y\\ z\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Let us write $A(x)$ for the $2\times 2$ matrix above. For a given vector $\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\ c_2\end{bmatrix}$, a solution will be given by 
$$
e^{B(x)}\,\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\ c_2\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $B'(x)=A(x)$. That is $B(x)=\begin{bmatrix}0&x\\-q(x)&0\end{bmatrix}$, with $q(x)=x^5/5+x^3/3+x^2/2+cx$. If I didn't make a mistake, the exponential is 
$$
e^{B(x)}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\sqrt{xq(x)}&\sqrt\frac{x}{q(x)}\,\sin\sqrt{xq(x)}\\
-\sqrt\frac{q(x)}{x}\,\sin\sqrt{xq(x)}&\cos\sqrt{xq(x)}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
As $y$ will be the first coordinate of $e^{B(x)}\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\ c_2\end{bmatrix}$, we get
$$
y(x)=c_1\,\cos\sqrt{\frac{x^6}5+\frac{x^4}3+\frac{x^3}2+cx^2}+c_2\,\frac{\sin\sqrt{\frac{x^6}5+\frac{x^4}3+\frac{x^3}2+cx^2}}{\sqrt{\frac{x^5}5+\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^2}2+cx}}.
$$

Comment: Ahh.. I'm not sure what went wrong but I'm not getting it equal to zero when I plug it in to the ode.

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong. But I cannot find it right away.

Answer (score 1):

I am reasonably sure that this equation has no nice solution. If it did, it would be of the form $y(x) = \exp(\int u(x)),$ where $u$ is a rational function.If you want to know more, read  [this fairly nice summary of Kovacic's algorithm by Carolyn Smith.](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1984/CS-84-35.pdf)