# Ordinary differential equation with polynomial terms

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

The original equation I had was:

$$-y''+(x^2+2x^4-2\alpha)y=0$$

Where $\alpha$ is a real parameter $\geq 0$ and we require the solutions to go to $0$ at infinity. With the substitution $y=p(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ I got the equation:

$$-p''+2xp'+p(1+2x^4-2\alpha)=0$$

I tried the power series method, getting:

$$a_2=(\frac{1}{2}-\alpha)a_0$$
$$a_3=\frac{(\frac{3}{2}-\alpha)a_1}{3}$$
$$a_4=\frac{(\frac{5}{2}-\alpha)(\frac{1}{2}-\alpha)a_0}{6}$$
$$a_5=\frac{(\frac{7}{2}-\alpha)(\frac{3}{2}-\alpha)a_1}{30}$$

And after $n=4$:

$$a_{n+2}=\frac{2(n+\frac{1}{2}-\alpha)a_n+2a_{n-4}}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

Are the solutions to this equation known? What would you do?

Comment: The d.e. can be transformed into a Heun equation, but the general solution does not appear to have a closed form, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun_function, http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=HeunT .

Comment: What information do you need in the end (the solutions, really?)? I have once studied the parameter dependent eigenvalue problem  $-y''(x)+(x^2/2-\alpha)^2y(x)=\lambda(\alpha) y(x)$, and maybe you could use something we did there...

Comment: I expect, though, that the power series has to terminate due to the conditions at infinity (this comes from the Schroedinger's equation) and therefore has to be a polynomial.

Comment: @mickep For example, for what values of $\alpha$ the solutions $y(x)$ don't blow up at infinity?

Comment: I doubt that you will have a polynomial times $e^{-x^2/2}$ as solution. You could have a look [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0872) and [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2141) for some spectral properties of the lowest eigenvalues of the above mentioned operator.

Comment: @Travis How this relates to Heun equation?

Comment: @doraemonpaul One can write the general solution as $y(x) = C_1 \exp q(x) \operatorname{HeunT}(\cdots) + C_2 \exp [-q(x)] \operatorname{HeunT}(\cdots)$ for an appropriate polynomial $q$ and arguments $\cdots$ (the sign of the last of which is different in the two occurrences of the expression). Here $\operatorname{HeunT}$ is the solution of the "Heun Triconfluent" function in a normal form recorded in: Decarreau, A.; Dumont-Lepage, M.C.; et al. "Formes Canoniques de Equations confluentes de l'equation de Heun". *Annales de la Societe Scientifique de Bruxelles*. **92** I-II, (1978): pp. 53-78.

Comment: @Travis I understand what you mean when read http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635314.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $u=x^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{du}\dfrac{du}{dx}=2x\dfrac{dy}{du}$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(2x\dfrac{dy}{du}\right)=2x\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{dy}{du}\right)+2\dfrac{dy}{du}=2x\dfrac{d}{du}\left(\dfrac{dy}{du}\right)\dfrac{du}{dx}+2\dfrac{dy}{du}=2x\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}2x+2\dfrac{dy}{du}=4x^2\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}+2\dfrac{dy}{du}=4u\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}+2\dfrac{dy}{du}$

$\therefore4u\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}+2\dfrac{dy}{du}-(2u^2+u-2\alpha)y=0$

Comment: That is a transformation I had not tried. However, is the equation you wrote known?