# Why are the two ODE solutions linearly independent?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, sturm-liouville

I notice that some second-order ODEs can be related to the triconfluent Heun's equation
$$u''(z)-(3z^2+\gamma)u'(z)+(\alpha-(3-\beta) z)u(z)=0.$$
And people usually say the general solution of the original ODE contains two parts like [from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/635424/87069) for the ODE $y'' +(x^4 +x^2+x+c)y(x) =0$]
$$ y( x ) ={C_1}\,{{\rm e}^{\frac{1}{6}\,ix \left( 2\,{x}^{2}+3\right)}}{\mathrm{HeunT}} \left(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, x \right) 
+{ C_2} {{\rm e}^{-\frac{1}{6}\,ix \left( 2\,{x}^{2}+3\right)}}  {\mathrm{HeunT}} \left( \alpha,-\beta, \gamma, -x\right).$$
Such a solution form is also generated in many examples in *Maple* and *Mathematica*. E.g., [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/635428/87069) and [another one](https://mathoverflow.net/a/253125/121010).

The two parts are indeed solutions as one can easily transform the original ODE to obtain. But they seem to be just different transforms of the ODE [just use $y(x)={{\rm e}^{\pm\frac{1}{6}\,ix \left( 2\,{x}^{2}+3\right)}} u(x)$].
**How to see they are linearly independent?**